# Display a certain value based on a condition in my Emberjs Model

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to Emberjs since I come from java server side world.

The actual case I'm facing to is the following.
I got a Member model, like this

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstname : DS.attr('string'),
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),
  ...      
  paid_fees : DS.hasMany('paid-fee', {async : true})
});
```

... and the paid-fee Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  year : DS.attr('number'),
  amount: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Here is my problem, how to display a list of member and in one of the column, display for example an 'V' if one of the paid-fees has the year 2016.

Here is the template I wrote:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Gsm</th>
    <th>En ordre de côtisations</th>
    <th>Détails</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  {{#each model as |member|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{member.firstname}}</td>
      <td>{{member.lastname}}</td>
      <td>{{member.email}}</td>
      <td>{{member.mobilePhone}}</td>
      <td>
          /*
How-TO ??? Component ? Computed property ? Helpers ?
*/

      </td>

      <td>{{#link-to 'members.show' member}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in" />{{/link-to}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{else}}
  No data available
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help ?
Thanks 
Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a PromiseObject which will let you have a computed property that returns a promise which proxies its value:

```
hasPaidThisYear: Ember.computed('paid_fees.@each.year', function() {
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
        promise: this.get('paid_fees').then(function(paidFees) {
            return paidFees.any(function(paidFee) {
                return paidFee.get('year') === 2016;
            });
        })
    });
})
```

just put this in the Member model, and you will be able to use `{{if member.hasPaidThisYear 'V'}}` in your template.

API docs for PromiseObject: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html

Comment: it seems that the use of {{if member.hasPaidThisYear 'V'}} cause the trouble

Comment: @OlivierAntoine check out [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
the some() method is valid in javascript 1.6 but not in Ember.

I had to use the any methods on Enumerable to get it work

```
  hasPaidThisYear: Ember.computed('paid_fees.@each.year', function() {
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
        promise: this.get('paid_fees').then(function(paidFees) {
            return paidFees.any(function(paidFee) {
                return paidFee.get('year') === 2016;
            });
        })
    });
})
```